# How to mock variables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

When writing nodejs unit test case I want to mock variables.

let abc = awsMock.service.lambda;

In above code, awsMock I am creating and passing to method but service is json object which I want to mock. How I can pass some dummy value when above line is executed?

I want awsMock to be mock object only as I want to mock method using this after above code is executed.

I tried to stub variable but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share code example about what've you tried while mocking the aws service?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you encapsulate that clases who you need to mock in a service container and you can replace that values in your mock files.

I will use a minimal example case with three files:

```text
- sc.js  : The service container
- main.js: The main function
- test.js: The main function for tests
```

**sc.js**

```javascript
// FAKE CLASS
class Lambda {
    foo() {
        return "real";
    }
}
// END FAKE CLASS

// CODE START HERE
// The service container: could be an object, class, etc...
const serviceContainer = {
    lambda: new Lambda(),
};

// Export SC
module.exports.sc = serviceContainer;

// Export properties with a wrap function (this is more easy to handle)
module.exports.getLambda = () => serviceContainer.lambda;
```

**main.js**

```javascript
const { getLambda } = require("./sc");

module.exports.main = () => {
    // Get lambda
    const lambda = getLambda();
    
    // Print foo()
    console.log(lambda.foo());
}
```

**test.js**

```javascript
const { sc } = require("./sc");
const { main } = require("./main");

// Exec before mock
main();

// Mock replace
sc.lambda = new class LambdaMock {
    foo() {
        return "mock";
    }
}

// Exec after mock
main();
```

If you execute `node test.js` the output will be:

```text
real
mock
```

So, you could use the `getLambda()` function in each file to get the Lambda Instance or the Mocked Lambda Instance.

*NOTE: As a recommendation, you must wrap the AWS Lambda class in another class to make ensure the real and the mocked version will have the same functions.*